# how to count positive and negative numbers of a column after applying groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

have the following dataframe:

```
      token name   ltp    change
0   12345.0  abc   2.0       NaN
1   12345.0  abc   5.0  1.500000
2   12345.0  abc   3.0 -0.400000
3   12345.0  abc   9.0  2.000000
4   12345.0  abc   5.0 -0.444444
5   12345.0  abc  16.0  2.200000
6    6789.0  xyz   1.0       NaN
7    6789.0  xyz   5.0  4.000000
8    6789.0  xyz   3.0 -0.400000
9    6789.0  xyz  13.0  3.333333
10   6789.0  xyz   9.0 -0.307692
11   6789.0  xyz  20.0  1.222222
```

I need to count of positive and negative number for each category of the name column. in above example

```
abc:pos_count: 3 abc:neg_count:2
xyz:pos_count:2 xyz:neg_count:2
```

---

```
count=df.groupby('name')['change'].count()
count
```

however, this gives me only the total count by group but not the positive & negative count separately.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
g = df.groupby('name')['change']
counts = g.agg(
    pos_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum(),
    neg_count=lambda s: s.lt(0).sum(),
    net_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum()- s.lt(0).sum()).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
# print(counts)
     pos_count  neg_count  net_count
name                                 
abc           3          2          1
xyz           3          2          1
```

Comment: Thanks, what should I do to get net change for each of the name?

Comment: @pushkala What do you mean by net change? `pos - neg` or `pos + neg`?

Comment: net change here is pos-neg

Comment: @pushkala Updated the answer.

Comment: this works excellent, but very slow as the entire data capture and calculation is in the the same function and the for loop. can I split this into another function which is more like a continuation so that it can work faster.

Comment: sorry, did not post the entire code. will post it separate

Comment: just posted as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column added by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then count values by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
count=(df.assign(type=np.sign(df['change'])
                      .map({1:'pos_count', -1:'neg_count'}))
        .groupby(df['name'])['type']
        .value_counts()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (count)
  name       type  count
0  abc  pos_count      3
1  abc  neg_count      2
2  xyz  pos_count      3
3  xyz  neg_count      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column in `df` with the sign of `change` and group by `name` and sign:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['change_sign'] = np.sign(df['change'])
df.groupby(['name','change_sign']).count()
```

You can then pivot if you need the result in columns instead of rows