# pd.NamedAgg overwrites previous columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

This is the dataframe I used.

```
      token name   ltp    change
0   12345.0  abc   2.0       NaN
1   12345.0  abc   5.0  1.500000
2   12345.0  abc   3.0 -0.400000
3   12345.0  abc   9.0  2.000000
4   12345.0  abc   5.0 -0.444444
5   12345.0  abc  16.0  2.200000
6    6789.0  xyz   1.0       NaN
7    6789.0  xyz   5.0  4.000000
8    6789.0  xyz   3.0 -0.400000
9    6789.0  xyz  13.0  3.333333
10   6789.0  xyz   9.0 -0.307692
11   6789.0  xyz  20.0  1.222222
```

While trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014890/how-to-count-positive-and-negative-numbers-of-a-column-after-applying-groupby-in#62015001), I encountered this wierd behaviour of [`pd.NamedAgg`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

```
#Worked as intended
df.groupby('name').agg(pos=pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x: x.gt(0).sum()),\
                       neg = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.lt(0).sum()))
# Output
      pos  neg
name
abc   3.0  2.0
xyz   3.0  2.0
```

When doing it over specific column

```
df.groupby('name')['change'].agg(pos = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.gt(0).sum()),\
                                 neg = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.lt(0).sum()))
#Output
      pos  neg
name
abc   2.0  2.0
xyz   2.0  2.0
```

`pos` columns values are over-written with `neg` column values.

Another example below:

```
df.groupby('name')['change'].agg(pos = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.gt(0).sum()),\
                                 neg = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.sum()))
#Output
           pos       neg
name
abc   4.855556  4.855556
xyz   7.847863  7.847863
```

More weirder results:

```
df.groupby('name')['change'].agg(pos = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.gt(0).sum()),\
                                 neg = pd.NamedAgg(column='change',aggfunc=lambda x:x.sum()),\
                                 max = pd.NamedAgg(column='ltp',aggfunc='max'))

# I'm applying on Series `'change'` but I mentioned `column='ltp'` which should
# raise an `KeyError: "Column 'ltp' does not exist!"` but it produces results as follows

           pos       neg  max
name
abc   4.855556  4.855556  2.2
xyz   7.847863  7.847863  4.0
```

The problem is when using it with `pd.Series`

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5])
s.groupby(s.values).agg(one = pd.NamedAgg(column='new',aggfunc='sum'))

   one
1    2
2    4
3    6
4    4
5    5
```

Shouldn't it raise an `KeyError`?

Some more weird results, The values `one` column are not over-written when we use different column names.

```
s.groupby(s.values).agg(one=pd.NamedAgg(column='anything',aggfunc='sum'),\
                        second=pd.NamedAgg(column='something',aggfunc='max'))

   one  second       
1    2       1     
2    4       2
3    6       3
4    4       4
5    5       5
```

Values are over-written when we use the same column name in `pd.NamedAgg`

```
s.groupby(s.values).agg(one=pd.NamedAgg(column='weird',aggfunc='sum'),\
                        second=pd.NamedAgg(column='weird',aggfunc='max'))

  one  second  # Values of column `one` are over-written
1  1       1
2  2       2
3  3       3
4  4       4
5  5       5
```

---

My pandas version

```
pd.__version__
# '1.0.3'
```

From the pandas documentation:

Named aggregation is also valid for Series groupby aggregations. In this case there’s no column selection, so the values are just the functions.

```
In [82]: animals.groupby("kind").height.agg(
   ....:     min_height='min',
   ....:     max_height='max',
   ....: )
   ....: 
Out[82]: 
      min_height  max_height
kind                        
cat          9.1         9.5
dog          6.0        34.0
```

But couldn't find why using it with `column` produces weird results.

**UPDATE :**

Bug report is filed by [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) in [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) [issue `#34380`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34380), and [here too.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34380#issuecomment-633839661)

**EDIT:** This is a bug confirmed by pandas-dev and this has been resolved in PR [BUG: aggregations were getting overwritten if they had the same name `#30858`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30858)

Answer (score 2):

If there is specified columns after groupby use solution specified in [paragraph](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

> Named aggregation is also valid for Series groupby aggregations. In this case there’s no column selection, so the values are just the functions.

```
df = df.groupby('name')['change'].agg(pos = lambda x:x.gt(0).sum(),\
                                      neg = lambda x:x.lt(0).sum())
print (df)
      pos  neg
name          
abc   3.0  2.0
xyz   3.0  2.0
```

> why using it with column produces weird results.

I think it is bug, instead wrong output is should raise error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I did not understand why using with `pd.NamedAgg` caused that weird behaviour.

Comment: @Ch3steR - I think it is wrong using, correctly is should raise error.

Comment: Yes, if it was not intended to work that way, it should raise an error. May be reporting it in GitHub might be helpful.

Comment: @Ch3steR - yop, give me some time.

Comment: Yes, I'll wait for you and others to give an answer. Else we can collectively open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: @Ch3steR - I create issue - [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34380)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe they can confirm what's happening under the hood. Mind if I add the github issue link to the question?

Comment: @Ch3steR - I add link to my answer after confim by pandas devs, be free use it like you need ;)

Comment: Updated the question with further more weirder results. Please take a look at it. Should we open another issue or update the existing issue with the new details?